# How to get Go To Definition for typescript on VS Code?

Tags: typescript, express, visual-studio-code

Currently I have the following as seen in the image.
I want to be able to hover over the type in the function
`DeletePostParams` and view the type definition or be able to "Go to definition."

What do I have to change/install/enable?
I have tried to research similar issues people encountered on Github and Stackoverflow but haven't found anything that works for me.

Extensions I have installed:
JavaScript and TypeScript Nightly,
Visual Studio Intellicode

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "compilerOptions": {                   
    "target": "es5",                                
    "module": "commonjs",                                                    
    "allowJs": true,                            
    "strict": true,                                
    "esModuleInterop": true,                        
    "skipLibCheck": true,                           
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true        
  }
}
```

babel.config.cjs:

```
  presets: [
    ["@babel/preset-env", { targets: { node: "current" } }],
    "@babel/preset-typescript",
  ],
};
```

[image]

Comment: Could u show the main code in codesandbox or the file `setting.json` of vscode? Maybe I haven't install any extensions about typescript yet, but it works.

Comment: settings.json

````{
    "javascript.updateImportsOnFileMove.enabled": "always",
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "files.autoSave": "afterDelay",
    "files.autoSaveDelay": 2500,
    "editor.suggestSelection": "first",
    "vsintellicode.modify.editor.suggestSelection": "automaticallyOverrodeDefaultValue"
} ````

Comment: sry, I can not figure out from the info above

Comment: Can you copy and paste your settings.json?

Comment: Of course yea, I have replaced my `setting.json`, but it still works for types